# calling javascript function on onclick of dynamically added dom element using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi I faced this issue long back and I wasted lot of time to figure out what is wrong. 
Let me tell the scenario. Suppose I have a html page in that I have few elements which are already in page and I am adding few more dynamically using ajax call. In adding new items to page I got the scenario like I need to add onClick function call for one of the element along with a object as a parameter.
But when I add that in jquery the function is getting called but the object I get in function is not the same as the object I pass in. The object is getting converted to String instead of object.

```
<html>
<body>
.
.
.
... Some html code....
.
.
.
.
<div onclick="function1();"> </div>
.
.
<div id="dynamicElement"> </div>
.
.
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function function1(){
   .
   .
   $.ajax(){

    success(obj):{ 
          $("#dynamicElement").empty().append('<input id="iButton" type="button" onclick="function2('+obj+')">')
        }
   }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function2(obj){
   //Here When I try to manipulate with this object. I was actually not abt to do.
   // this is because of the object u add in dynamic elements will get converted to string instead of ibject.
 }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is where jQuery starts to trip up. You've reached the edge of what a library like jQuery can do for you. _Nice_ solutions lie in the domain of document fragment notation libraries. ie. you want to specify an onclick handler inline, but you don't want messy string casts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is. We need to add onclick even externally instead of specifying it while adding element itself.

Solution for above example:
In Ajax call just add button element.

```
$.ajax(){

    success(obj):{ 
          $("#dynamicElement").empty().append('<input id="iButton" type="button">');
      $("#iButton").onClick({
          function2(obj);
         });
        }
   }
```

Now it works perfectly.